# Avoid printing attributes of the nil object in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, null, erb

Currently, when I'm wanting to print a value for my class I do the following...

```
<%= @person.team.name if @person.team.present? %>
```

This seems really redundant to me.  I've also have done...

```
<%= @person.team.name_display %>
```

where I've created a function for each attribute to kind of hide the first case.  It seems a little much though. Is there a more preferred way to do it such as...

```
<%= @person.team.name || "" %>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right, you code is too verbose. This is a pretty common pattern and you have some alternatives. For example, *active_support* has the abstraction `Object#try`:

```
<%= @person.team.try(:name) %>
```

Another alternative is the `Object#maybe` proxy: https://github.com/bhb/maybe

```
<%= @person.team.maybe.name %>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a delegate method on your `Person` class:

```
class Person
  def team_name
    team.name unless team.nil?
  end
end
```

Then it's just a simple:

```
<%= @person.team_name %>
```

If you have a lot of these, consider using the [Delegate](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) module:

```
class Person
  delegate :name, :ranking, :jersey, :grounds,
             :to => :team, :allow_nil => true, :prefix => true
  # Person now responds to #team_name, #team_ranking, #team_jersey, #team_grounds as above
end
```

The reason this approach works better has to do with the [Principle of Least Knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter):

> The Law of Demeter (LoD) or principle of least knowledge is a design guideline for developing software, particularly object-oriented programs. In its general form, the LoD is a specific case of loose coupling. The guideline was proposed at Northeastern University towards the end of 1987, and can be succinctly summarized in each of the following ways:
>
> - Each unit should have only limited knowledge about other units: only units "closely" related to the current unit.
> - Each unit should only talk to its friends; don't talk to strangers.
> - **Only talk to your immediate friends.**

(Emphasis, mine)

The last bullet point is the key. Your view should only be calling methods on `@person`. In order to get the team name, your view should not need to test for the existence of `@person.team`. That requires your view to have too much knowledge of the `@person` object, and instead it is preferable to create a delegate method in `Person` that checks for `team.nil?`.

Comment: @ymbirtt: Good catch on the Delegate module. I forgot about that one.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the safe navigation operator like so:
    `<%= @person.team&.name %>`

http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/

Answer (score 0):

I believe the idiomatic Rails approach is to use [`Object#presence`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/presence):

```
<%= @person.team.name.presence || '' %>
```

This checks for false, empty, whitespace and nil.

Comment: But what if `team` is the nil object, not name?  I can't test that case right this second but I don't believe the above will work in that instance.

Comment: Then you would need to use try's: `<%= @person.try(:team).try(:name).presence || '' %>`

Comment: how is that better than `<%= @person.team.try(:name) %>`? I do not mean that to come off as a harsh response either, just curious if it's truly a better way. Thanks!

Comment: The advantage of `presence` is how it deals with an empty string or array value. It would particularly make sense if you do: `@person.try(:team).try(:name).presence || 'Default Value'` and want `Default Value` to show if name returns an empty string.